# Fatal Civi Error: "Invalid cache key: Not a string" error in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

I'm using Wordpress 4.9.9 and CiviCRM 5.4.1. Earlier today I updated several plugins, everything works fine except Civi.

** UPDATE: With civi activated, I get a blank page any time I try to edit a Wordpress page.

I also get a blank page when I try to go to the Civi dashboard in Wordpress and I cannot access any Civi pages such as event registration or membership pages.

In a Wordpress log I get:

```
2019-02-14T22:19:10+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Invalid 
cache key: Not a string

thrown in /var/www/vhosts/<site>/httpdocs/wp- 
content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Cache.php on line 236
```

That code is in the assertValidKey function.

Any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: Is this reproducible? If so, can you log what the cache key is at that point in the script?

Comment: How was this issue fixed ? I have upgraded recently to 5.15.1 but it shows me error as well and site is down due to this